# Is it possible to use the map interface with io.vavr.collection.HashMap?

Tags: java, vavr

Whilst trying to use [Vavr](http://www.vavr.io/)'s immutable map (`io.vavr.collection.HashMap`) with the `java.util.Map` interface, I did not manage to get the code to compile -  at least not by using the `.of()` static method in  `io.vavr.collection.HashMap`.

In essence this is the Maven dependency I am using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
    <artifactId>vavr</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

with Java 1.8

And this is the code:

```
import io.vavr.collection.HashMap;

import java.util.Map;

public class EntityKeyMap {

    public static final Map<String, String> map = 
            HashMap.of("key1", "val1", "key2", "val2", "key3", "val3");

    private EntityKeyMap() {
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Incompatible types. Required Map but 'of' was inferred
>   to HashMap: no instance(s) of type variable(s) K, V exist so
>   that HashMap conforms to Map

Any ideas how you can assign an instance of `io.vavr.collection.HashMap` to `java.util.Map`? Is that even possible?

According to `io.vavr.collection.HashMap` documentation it implements the `java.util.Map` interface:

https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/collection/HashMap.html

There are some examples on the web where it seems to be possible, like on this [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/vavr-collections) where you can find this code:

```
Map<String, String> map1
  = HashMap.of("key1", "val1", "key2", "val2", "key3", "val3");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vavr's `HashMap` doesn't implement [JDK's `Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface. The `Map` interface it implements is [vavr's own `Map`](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/collection/Map.html) interface.

In contrast with JDK's `Map`, vavr's `Map` represents an *immutable* map, [`HashMap`](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/collection/HashMap.html) being an efficient persistent map implementation based on [Hash array mapped trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie).

The most fundamental difference between the JDK `Map` interface and the vavr `Map` interface is that the JDK map has methods that *mutate* the map's internal state, while vavr's methods always return a new `Map` instance (or the same instance in case the map didn't change).

Compare JDK's [`Map.put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) vs vavr's [`Map.put`](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/collection/Map.html#put-K-V-) method signatures.

**JDK `Map.put`**:

```java
V put(K key, V value)
```

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map (optional operation). If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value. (A map m is said to contain a mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k) would return true.)
>   **Returns:** the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key, if the implementation supports null values.)

**vavr `Map.put`**:

```java
Map<K,V> put(K key, V value)
```

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.
>   **Returns:** A new Map containing these elements and that entry.

If you need a JDK Map, you can convert the vavr map with [`Map.toJavaMap`](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/collection/Map.html#toJavaMap--), but that will create a full copy of the map contents, as the mutable nature of the JDK map is incompatible with the immutable approach of vavr.

Comment: Oh, yes, I have overseen that it is another Map interface. Thank you very much for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

There is the `toJavaMap` method  exactly for this purpose:

> Converts this Vavr Map to a java.util.Map while preserving characteristics like insertion order (LinkedHashMap) and sort order (SortedMap).

```
import io.vavr.collection.HashMap;

public class VavrPlayground {

   public static final HashMap<String, String> map =
       HashMap.of("key1", "val1", "key2", "val2", "key3", "val3");

   public void EntityKeyMap() {
      java.util.Map<String, String> jMap = map.toJavaMap();
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of this method.